# emacs ssh client on windows

Tags: microsoft-windows, emacsclient

I have emacs installed on linux machine, and for most times, I need to connect to the machine on my windows laptop, previous I use putty, but I found it has issue with emacs keybindings, some key bindings are blocked. Is there any ssh client tool on windows that can exactly send all the key events to remote linux machine just like I am typing on the remote machine?

Comment: Not every key combination can be used in a terminal, for instance control shift letter key combinations aren't recognized. Consider tunneling X over ssh to get a remote connection to Emacs with a graphical interface.

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10, thanks, but tunneling X doesn't work perfectly for me, it always sending some random key during my test.

Comment: It would help to know which key combinations specifically.  I use emacs inside putty all the time with no issues but I tend to use CUA more.  You can change the terminal emulation putty under terminal->keyboard, which may help.